# How do Wikipedias in different languages share list and table articles?

Tags: wikipedia

Different Wikipedias (in different languages) have different policies on creating lists and tables in articles and keeping them in separate articles. However for most of list and table articles (think about a list of software of topic x) sharing resources makes a lot of sense for two Wikipedias that have the same policy.

How is that done, speaking of templating and location of the shared resource?

Examples:

- The articles on wiki software in the [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Wiki-Software) and the [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software)
- The [article about continuous integration in the German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontinuierliche_Integration) and the [discussion about recreating such a list in the English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Continuous_integration#List_of_CI_software) (which would mean double maintenance for two articles)

Comment: Can you link to some examples?  A lot of data is stored in WikiData but I'm not sure that's what you're referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is currently no sharing of data in lists among different Wikipedias. Though [this might be possible in the the future using Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Lists).